# Exclude some folders, while doing electron-packager . --asar

Tags: electron

I use 'electron-packager . --asar' command to package my project folder. but there are some folders which must not be included while packaging.

1. Is it possible to exclude some of folders?
2. If so, I would like to include those folders in exe file path so that the user can manage their files. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it possible to exclude some of folders?**

Yes, you can do it with `ignore`

> You can use --ignore to ignore files and folders via a regular
>   expression (not a glob pattern). Examples include --ignore=.gitignore
>   or --ignore=".git(ignore|modules)".

Take a look at API document [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/c0c801465921db516605a1fb5c843f640c54dbb4/docs/api.md#ignore)

**If so, I would like to include those folders in exe file path so that the user can manage their files. Is there any way to do this?**

You can use `extraResource` API to include them to `resources` directory (document [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/c0c801465921db516605a1fb5c843f640c54dbb4/docs/api.md#extraresource)):

> **extraResource**
>
> *String or Array of Strings*
>
> One or more files to be copied directly into the app's
>   Contents/Resources directory for OS X target platforms, and the
>   resources directory for other target platforms.

Hope this help.

Comment: It would be really nice if you could provide an example of its usage. I can't seem to get it to work in my case, which I have a folder with the path ./app/JSON/ but I couldn't make it leave this folder outside of the asar package.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. I wanted to exclude **qpdf** folder containing (*.exe, *.dll) from asar package. My qpdf.exe could not run without needed linked .dll directly from asar package.

I just added `--extra-resource` parameter into electron packager syntax where I am excluding whole **qpdf** folder. This folder and all files inside are then in resource folder with asar package.

**Part of my package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . hiss_xread --overwrite --extra-resource=\"./qpdf\" --asar --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=src/xRead.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Hiss xRead\""
  },
```

**Resource folder in builded app look like this.**

[image]