# I want to don't build one specific directory of my Electron app packaged with electron-packager

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, electron-packager

i am working on an Code Editor as a web app thanks to Electron.
My problem is short:

When I build my app with electron-packager all my web folders and files goes to the file called "app.asar". But i want to have an exception  for my folder called "Themes" so it will be as a folder inside the app folder and not inside the "app.asar" file.

It would amazing i get some answer. Thank you guys :)

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587974/exclude-some-folders-while-doing-electron-packager-asar/53604617#53604617

Comment: @HaiPham Thank you! I didn't see it before ask it, thank you :)

Comment: Yes, just vote up if you see it's helpful.