# Executable Electron App cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an electron app that works when running locally, but when creating an executable it cannot find a module (JSON file) and I'm not sure why.

The error I get is "Uncaught Exception" Cannot find module './data/background/background.json' Require Sack :

```
 var background = require('./data/background/background.json');
```

This is the code that is causing the error. I don't understand because when I run my app locally with npm start, it works.

To deploy my app I ran

```
npm install --save-dev electron-packager
```

and my package.json file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "moveanimator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Create Move Animations for Fire Red",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Move Animation Creator\"",    
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "author": "ortz3",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "check-disk-space": "^3.0.1",
    "electron": "^13.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^15.3.0"
  }
}
```

I then ran npm run package-win which created the executable in a release build folder, but opening the executable results in an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executable Electron App cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868267/executable-electron-app-cannot-find-module)

Comment: @Joshua They have posted the same question twice.

Comment: @Joshua I got a server error when posting the question. I clicked post again. I guess it posted twice. I deleted the other question

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour I see, I tried closing as a duplicate but I guess that's not what I should have done, is there anything else you'd recommend? Or should we just leave this question up?

Comment: I deleted the duplicate question

Comment: @Joshua No, Just keep the question up. I didn't find any duplicate targets. If you find anything, so just vote to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the `--asar` option.

Because you have this option turned on `electron-packager` will package your source code into an `app.asar` file **including your `data` folder**.

Because your `data` folder has now been compressed with all your other source code into this `app.asar` file your code can no longer access it.

Solution 1:

- Take out: `--asar`

Solution 2:

- Add this option: `--extra-resource=\"./data\"`
- This'll tell `electron-packager` not to include `./data` in the `app.asar`.

[Read more about `--asar`](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#asar)

[Read more about `--extra-resource`](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#extraresource)

[Also see this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587974/exclude-some-folders-while-doing-electron-packager-asar)

Comment: Removing --asar solved the problem. Thank you1